# Query for parent in hierarchy

Tags: hierarchy

Trying to query the main parent in the hierarchy.

I have a case whose related account is a child of another account in hierarchy. Can someone please suggest how to query for the main parent in the hierarchy ?

Current Query:

```
SELECT Id, accountId from case
```

Need to modify the above statement to something like

```
SELECT Id, accountId.parent from case
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than getting the parent of the AccountId, as you're trying to at the moment.

You need to instead traverse the Account relationship and get the details of the parent from there.

```
SELECT Id, Account.ParentId FROM Case
```

You can [read more about Relationship Queries here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm).